# Selenium ChromeDriver allow cookies ( default profile)

Tags: java, selenium, web-scraping, cookies

I did a search and I couldn't find this type of problem posted on stack overflow.
And I did read documentation on the https://chromedriver.chromium.org/capabilities but couldn’t find any meaningful examples. I found examples about add cookies but not about allow a cookie.

The problem:

Basically, I try to access and **scrape** a site but as soon as I try to access the url with:

```
webDriver.get(urlAddress);
```

a pop-up window appears which prompt me to accept all cookies.

My work around now is to click the button like in the code below.

```
 List<WebElement> acceptAllCookies =
             webDriver.findElements(By.id("ccc-notify-accept"));

 if (!acceptAllCookies.isEmpty()) {
     acceptAllCookies.get(0).click();
     WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(webDriver, 2);
 }
```

And then proceed with **scraping**.

I went to chrome://settings and add the site on to the “Sites that can always use cookies” and the pop up doesn’t show when I access it manually. But when I try programmatically the pop-up appears again.

I do not know how to load my chrome profile . I tried

```
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
//Path to your chrome profile which allows
//cookyes from londonstockexchange
options.addArguments("user-data-dir= My User Data\\Default");
driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
```

But didn’t seem to work. I do not know how to configure the capabilities to allow cookies only for that specific site

Will be something like:

```
options.setCapability("____", _____);
```

I don't know what to add in the blanks to always allow cookie for a specific site.

Can someone please help fill in the blanks above or point me to some examples?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56150874/remote-run-selenium-test-cases-for-download-file-test-using-chrome/56151484#56151484